# The relation $R$ defined on $\mathbb{Z}$ by $aRb$ if and only if $a=(2^n)b$ prove/disprove symmetry, transitive and reflexive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, symmetry

The relation $\mathbf R$ defined on $\mathbb Z$ by $a\mathbf{R} b$ if and only if $\exists n, a=(2^n)b$

prove/disprove symmetry

prove/disprove transitive

prove/disprove reflexive

This was a question I had on my math test previously and it is driving me crazy. I was trying to use an induction proof but couldn't figure out what to put as my base case.

Comment: This is going to sound like I'm quibbling but does $n$ have to be a natural number?  Can $n = 0$?  Can $n$ be negative?  Can $n$ be any real number?

Comment: My point is the original question needs to be clarified.  I would assume that $n \in \mathbb N$ and that $\mathbb N$ includes $0$.  But it does need to be stated.  As it is written as only $Z$ is mentioned it appears $n$ may be negative but I highly doubt that was the original intent of the question.

Comment: @fleablood I will update the question today. Going to grab the exam now

Answer (score 0):

This is an order relation. It is transitive and reflexive, but asymmetric.

- Transitive since if $a=(2^n)b$ and $b=(2^m)c$ then $a=(2^{n+m})c$
- Reflexive since $a=2^0a$
- Assymetric since if $a=(2^n)b\wedge b=(2^m)a$ then $a=(2^{n+m})a$ so $n=m=0$ and therefore $a=b$

Comment: I'm going to quibble and say the OP never stated $n$ was natural.  If we assume $n$ can be a negative integer then it is symmetric.  If we assume $n$ is natural but the naturals do no include $0$ then it is not reflexive.  If we assume $n$ can be any real number then $0R 0$ and $aR b$ for all $a\ne 0; b\ne 0$.

Comment: First of all, these assumptions (excluding that $n\ne 0$) need to not be working on $\mathbb Z$, 
then if we assume $n$ can be any real number and we are working on $\mathbb R$ then we have three equivalence classes: ${0}$, $R_+^*$ and $R_-^*$ and not just two.

Comment: I'd quibble that $\exists n\in Z| a = b2^n$ does work on $\mathbb Z$.  If $b2^n \not \in \mathbb Z$ then $n$ fails to satisfy $a = b2^n$ so we don't have to consider it.

Comment: Yes you have reason

Comment: And in such case, I think that should be the symmetric closure of the original relation.

Answer (score 0):

Is $n \in \mathbb Z$?  Or is $n \in \mathbb N$?  And is $0 \in \mathbb N$.

If it must be $n\in \mathbb Z$:

$a = b2^n \iff b = a2^{-n}$ so $aRb \iff bRa$ so symmetric

But if $n$ must be be $n\in \mathbb N$ then

$a = b2^n \iff b = a2^{-n}$ but $n, -n \in \mathbb N$ only if $n =0$ and if $0 \in \mathbb Z$.  In that case $a=b$ and $R$ is not symmetric.  In fact it is anti-symmetric.

If $n\in \mathbb R$ is the only restriction it is symmetric by the first argument.  But notice that it will always be the case that $aRb$ if i) $a,b$ both positive. (Because $a = b2^{\log_2 \frac ab}$) ii) $a,b$ both negative (same reason) iii) $a = b =0$.  Making this a very simple relation:  $a Rb$ if and only if $a,b$ are either both positive, or both negative, or both $0$.

.....

I will assume the assumption is that $n \in \mathbb N$ and that $n$ may be $0$.  That just seems to be the standard.

So I'll say $R$ is not symmetric.

.....

Transitive.  If $a R b$ and $bRc$ then $a = 2^nb$ and $b= c2^{m}$ and $a = 2^{n+m}c$. So $a R c$.  So transitive.

Reflexive.  If $a = a*2^m$ either $a=0$ or $m= 0$.  So if $0$ is an acceptable value for $n$ then for every possible $a \in \mathbb Z$, $aRa$ so it is reflexive.

If however $0$ is *not* an acceptable value of $n$ then it is not reflexive.

Comment: here is the full question: For integers a and b, define aRb iff ∃n ∈ Z such that a=(2^n)b. Prove/disprove R is reflexive/symmetric/transitive